# How to automate setting django model attribute based on some condition?

Tags: python, django, class

```
class TimecardModel(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(max_length=16, blank=True, null=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(User)
    clock_in = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, editable=True)
    clock_out = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_clocked_out = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
```

I want to set **is_clocked_out = True** everytime when employee clock_out, how do I achieve this thing. I know that django singals can do the job, but can I write method on django model to do this. If I write one how this method will execute everytime emplyee clock_out. Do I need to call this or it will work everytime I save the model object. Will @property help me? then how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method which clocks out, and changes `is_clocked_out`. This will be less complicated than overriding the model’s `save()` method.

```
def clockout(self):
    self.clock_out = timezone.now()
    self.is_clocked_out = True
    self.save()
    return self.is_clocked_out
```

And then you can just clock out by calling this code via `instance.clockout()`

To override the `.save()` method, you can do this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.clock_out:
        self.is_clocked_out = True
    super(TimecardModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Will this work everytime when I call save() on model object? or do I need to call it somewhere?

Comment: @Appyens this will only work when you call `instantlce.clockout()`. If you want the code to automatically work on save, you will have to override the model’s default `.save()` method. I can show you how to do that as well, but it comes with its own drawbacks.

Comment: Thank you @Hybrid. Please show me how to override the save method.

Comment: @Appyens I updated my answer for you. Please keep in mind the `.save()` trick will keep updating the model if there is any value in `clock_out`. Also, this does not affect command line saves.